# How do I open a file in C++ using just the filename?

Tags: c++, file, io

Its a bit of a chore for me when coding in java and c++ to have to get the file path and add in an extra '\' so the compiler is not confused. Does anybody know how I can go about doing in out file operations using just the file name?

Here is some sample code:

```
int main(){

    char str[100];

    ifstream inStream;
    ofstream outStream;

    inStream.open("pre-html.txt"); //fails to open without file path

        if(inStream.fail()){
            cout << "File failed to open";
            exit(1);//exit(1) faster than exit(0)
        }

    //reads the data from the file
    while(inStream >> str){
        cout << str;
    }

}
```

Comment: why would "//exit(1) faster than exit(0)"

Comment: why would it even matter??

Comment: not sure tbh @user4581301. I'll clean that up.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was any backing to that. I admit it's mostly useless, but I can think of times I'd like a program to die faster after a failure so I can resurrect it with less downtime.

Comment: I guess C++ will usually read files inside the directory the program is executed in, if no absolute path is provided. This may be OS-dependent, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know how I can go about doing in out file operations using just the file name?

Start your program in the same directory where your file exists.

Comment: Recommend dropping in Working Directory as a keyword for OP to search.

Comment: @user4581301 You just did so ;)